# should i mix Razor Pages and Blazor, or keep them separate?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, signalr, blazor

We have an on-premises Windows 2019 server, serving a few large web forms projects. When the use case suits, I would like to start writing in Razor Pages and server-side Blazor. I've read that the SignalR connection (or webSockets) doesn't scale especially well and can use large amounts of memory with larger numbers of users.

I'm wanting to write in Razor Pages for some new stuff when it's appropriate, and in Blazor for stuff that I would otherwise have to write a load of Javascript for.

The question is, would it be better to have Razor Pages in a separate project/site from the Blazor stuff so that SignalR connections are kept to a minimum, or is that not really a concern?

Comment: Websockets don't scale especially well? FYI: this site uses websockets. Any other major site with real-time updates uses websockets. Websockets scale extremely well. Whether the service/server/architecture scale is another problem

Comment: I think both are ok. You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54630728/combining-mvc-blazor-in-the-same-project),and see what `tomRedox` says.